# Bring a SVG line to front

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add some circles and a redline above the circles to my SVG.
However, no matter in which order they are appended: I always have the line in the back.

How do I bring it to front?
I tried to use moveToFront and z-axis property but I cannot fix it.

My tentative:

```
d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "chart")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

filename = "assets/sources/datafile.csv"
d3.csv(filename, d => dataViz(d));

function dataViz(input_data) {
  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(input_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
}
d3.select("#chart")
  .append('line')
  .attr("id", "avg_line")
  .attr("x1", xScale(0))
  .attr("y1", yScale(3.75))
  .attr("x2", xScale(upper_limit))
  .attr("y2", yScale(3.75))
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("stroke", "red")
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an interesting variation of a well-known topic on `d3.json`! Since `d3.json` is **asynchronous** the callback will not be invoked before the loading has finished. Although the call to append the line *seems* to be located *after* appending the circles, it will actually execute right away, i.e. *before* appending the circles, whereby positioning the line under the circles in any case. The solution would be to append the line **inside** the callback after the circles were appended.

```
function dataViz(input_data) {
  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(input_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")

  d3.select("#chart")   // <-- This should be inside the callback.
    .append('line')
      .attr("id","avg_line")
      .attr("x1", xScale(0))
      .attr("y1", yScale(3.75))
      .attr("x2", xScale(upper_limit))
      .attr("y2", yScale(3.75))
      .attr("stroke-width",5)
      .attr("stroke","red");
}
```

Another mistake is in the way you select the elements to which you want to append to. The corrected code above will generate the following structure:

```
<svg>
  <g id="chart" width="" height="">
    <line id="avg_line" x1="" y1="" x2="" y2="" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"></line>
  </g>
  <circle></circle>
</svg>
```

This is because you are first appending a `<g id="chart">` to the `<svg>` to which only the line is appended. The circles on the other hand get appended to the `<svg>` itself. Looking at that structure it becomes apparent, why the line is still located behind the circles.

Given that you have not provided your full code I cannot tell for sure what the best solution would be. However, since a [`<g>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#GElement) is just a container element, which does not have `width` and `height` attributes, the first statement should ditch the `.append("g")`. On the other hand, because the `svg` is the element you want to append to, it is good practice to keep a reference to it, which also frees you from repeatedly re-selecting the same element:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")   // Keep the reference to the <svg> for later use.
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);
```

In your callback you are then able to use this reference to append the elements in the desired order. Putting all this together you end up with something like the following:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);

filename="assets/sources/datafile.csv"

d3.csv(filename, dataViz);

function dataViz(input_data) {
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(input_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")

  svg.append('line')
      .attr("id","avg_line")
      .attr("x1", xScale(0))
      .attr("y1", yScale(3.75))
      .attr("x2", xScale(upper_limit))
      .attr("y2", yScale(3.75))
      .attr("stroke-width",5)
      .attr("stroke","red");
}
```

The resulting SVG structure will look like the following, rendering the line above any circle:

```
<svg id="chart" width="" height="">
  <circle></circle>
  <line id="avg_line" x1="" y1="" x2="" y2="" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"></line>
</svg>
```

---

**Protip** not related to your problem:

Notice, how I simplified your call to `d3.csv()`. The following two statements are basically equivalent (well, before I get chastized, this is not *exactly* true, but in first-order approximation they are):

```
d3.csv(filename, d => dataViz(d));
d3.csv(filename, dataViz);
```

There is no need to wrap your function `dataViz()` in yet another anonymous arrow function; just pass in the reference to it, D3 will take care of invoking it.

Comment: Dear altocumulus, first of all thank you for answering. Before writing to stackoverflow, I had tried the solution you are suggesting but it does not work. This is because I tried to use teh MoveOnFront property. Unsucesfully.... I am a bit lost indeed...